# Mod Rewrite to IIS URL Rewrite Issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, iis-8

I need to host a PHP script on Windows server 2012 (IIS 8.0)

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

when I try to import these rules in URL_Rewrite in IIS I am getting following errors

[image]

I need help solving this issue. Thanks